# Macro/Script to find best board game to play - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadhseet I made with my friends that has our board game collection and the info for each game (estimated time needed to play, minimum people, max people, etc.)
I would like to create a page where I can enter the amount of people I have with me, and the amount of time I want to spend on a game.
When I would hit enter, the script would run and give me a list of eligible games to play given the amount of players and time I inputted.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFTr_ji5iz8BJU9_OkZ1Xhfb9hg9ARAaRXfdVx2Y8pU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include an example of the script you're using that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preface

This is an interesting question that can quickly grow up in scope.

While the number of players you have is a "fixed" value, the estimated time is not.

### The solution

When you say "eligible games" that means, all the games that fulfill the following conditions:

- Have `Min. Player >= your player input`
- Have `Max. Player <= your player input`
- Have `Est. Time <= your time input`

### Where things get interesting

While this can be done in a fairly simple way, I believe it would benefit you if you ranked these games based on how "fitting" they are.

To do this, you could use a system for sorting them based with some mathematical formulas:

- Since you know all the items returned have the Estimate Time of, at maximum, your input, you could create a score in the form of `(currentItemTime/MaximumTime) * timeScoreWeight`

  - Additionally you could change the score based on how many sessions of the game could be played on that time i.e.: with time slot of 1 hour, game A can be played once, but game B can be played twice. If you bring your player's rating into account, this could be used to find the optimal game for your situation based on past scores. This would also introduce the problem where *new/unrated games fall to the bottom quickly.*
- Since you have an Average Rating metric, you could also add that to the formula as `currentItemRating/5 * ratingWeight`.
- If you want to account for flexible table sizes, meaning, you are willing to run two games simultaneously with the same amount of people, you could also find what combinations of games exist where `numberOfPlayer <= (x+y)` where *x* is `a number >= minPlayer and <=maxPlayer` for game A and *y* is `a number >= minPlayer and <=maxPlayer` for game B.

If you add up all these rating, you can then sort by this number and get a list of the optimal games, sorted from best to worst to your situation.

### Coming back to earth

While dreaming is always good, I assume you want something finished fairly quickly, so, here is some code to get you started:

```
function test() {
  var gamesThatFitCriteria = findGames(4,50);
}

function findGames(player, timeInMinutes) {
  var games = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  games.shift(); //Remove first row
  games.shift(); //Remove second row
  
  var result = [];
  
  for (var i=0; i<games.length; i++) {
    var currentGame = games[i];
    
    var time = currentGame[2];
    var minPlayer = currentGame[3];
    var maxPlayer = currentGame[4];
    
    if (time<=timeInMinutes && player >= minPlayer && player <= maxPlayer) {
      //This is eligible.
      result.push(currentGame);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello ZektorH, I'll an editable link in the event I need more guidance... I created a page where I input the amount of players I have, and estimated game time. If I were to assign the script to the button, would that cause any issue into the current script?    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFTr_ji5iz8BJU9_OkZ1Xhfb9hg9ARAaRXfdVx2Y8pU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello @AlexGoral, it was my pleasure. In regards to sharing the sheet as editable I would advise against that since others might use that link maliciously. If you'd like, create a duplicate of this sheet and share that instead. That way you will always have your secure isolated copy.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @ZektorH, this is already a duplicated copy of my original spreadsheet, so no worries on if it is used maliciously.